# Issues with URI and C#: URI starts with "./", cannot be read or used as path

Tags: c#, formatting, uri, filepath

I have a simple function, that is supposed to take in one filepath, as a string, then create a relative path based on the main application working directory:

```
private string ConvertToLocal ( string path )
{
        Uri finalURI;

        Uri applicationURI = new Uri ( System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory );

        string rebuiltPath = applicationURI.ToString () + path;
        Uri targetURI = new Uri ( rebuiltPath );
        finalURI = applicationURI.MakeRelativeUri ( targetURI );

        return finalURI.ToString ();
}
```

It should return a nice simple string, which is afterwards used to save the relative URI. The idea is to allow to load assets independently of the current directory. I thought it would generate a path like "\Resources\Images\img.png", but it doesn't work that way. Not only that, but I keep getting an exception due to how the string is formatted, as it always comes with a dot slash at the beginning, such as: "./C:/Users/Foo/Bar/Resources/Images/img.png" and if I try to use that it produces an exception. I couldn't find any help, the documentation doesn't mention anything, so I am asking here hoping for some help. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the path C:/Users/Foo/Bar/Resources/Images/img.png to variable path。so the rebuildPath isnot a valid path and return an unexpected result .If you want to return like "/Resources/Images/img.png" 
you should set /Resources/Images/img.png to path variable.About MakeRelativeUri you can refer the below:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri(v=vs.100).aspx